# Mvvmcross Android Notification Pass Parameter to Existing ViewModel

Tags: android, notifications, mvvmcross

I have a foreground service with a notification. When the user clicks the notification, it will bring the user back to the main screen viewmodel (or load it again if unloaded).

I want to add 2 actions (pause, stop) to the notification. It is preferred to call the same viewmodel with a parameter to indicate the action type, and let the main screen viewmodel to handle the action. As the main screen viewmodel may have been loaded already, no more initialization will be executed. Passing parameter like showing viewmodel does not work. The existing viewmodel does not know it was triggered from the notification indeed.

How can I pass a different parameter for each action type to the viewmodel, and retrieve it in the viewmodel to act accordingly? Or it should be done in a different way?

This is the code of the notification:

```
                var request = MvxViewModelRequest<RouteLayoutViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
                var intent = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator>().GetIntentFor(request);
                const int pendingIntentId = 0;
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

                var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

                builder
                    .SetContentTitle(AppConstants.AppName)
                    .SetContentText("notification_text")
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent); ..........

                var notification = builder.Build();

                StartForeground(AppConstants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: There's an open [issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2418) in the MvvmCross repository for this issue. The changes to navigation in MvvmCross 5.x made this scenario more difficult. For now the only way I can make this work is to use `PendingIntent.GetBroadcast` and use the `IMvxNavigationService` in the `BroadcastReceiver` to navigate with parameters when the notification is clicked.

Comment: @TrevorBalcom Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please share some codes with me on how to create the pending intent with a parameter, and retrieve it in broadcastreceiver? I have no idea on how to initiate a self-defined broadcast and to use intent parameter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvvmCross 5 changed the way the ViewModel parameters are serialized internally. MvvmCross 5 hasn't been updated yet to handle this scenario AFAIK. Here is some sample code demonstrating how to workaround the issue using a BroadcastReceiver currently. This approach will allow you to navigate with parameters after the user clicks on the Android Notification.

When you're building the notification:

```
var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(YourBroadcastReceiver));
intent.SetAction("YOUR_ACTION");
// Put your other parameters here...
intent.PutExtra("id", id);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, _notificationId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
...
notificationBuilder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Then you add a BroadcastReceiver class like so:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class YourBroadcastReceiver : MvxBroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == "YOUR_ACTION")
        {
            // TODO: Extract the contents from the intent.
            var id = intent.GetIntExtra("id", 0);
            // TODO: Navigate using IMvxNavigationService using the parameters pulled from the Intent.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, thank you very much for the solution. I will handle the parameter in broadcast and navigate to the viewmodel as per your solution. In my viewmodel constructor, there are a number of tasks to run. I would like to avoid them if possible. When navigate to a viewmodel, it will construct a new viewmodel even there is an existing one being shown. Is it possible to navigate to an existing viewmodel, just like when clicking the notification in my original code?

Comment: I've not come up with the need to reuse the ViewModel so that is not something I have experience with, sorry. However, I don't think you should be doing any tasks in the ViewModel constructor at all. You want to do ViewModel initialization in the `Task Initialize` method. If you look at the sample `MyViewModel` in the [MvvmCross navigation documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation) you'll notice the comment "Do the heavy work here" is showing you where are expected to do initialization tasks.